# Dual space and norm to $X=c_0\times l^1$, solution check

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$$X=c_0\times l^1,\ \|(x,y)\|=\|x^\|_{\infty}+\|y\|_1$$
It is clear, that the dual space is isomorphic to $l^1\times l^\infty$ and the functional $x^*(x)$ is defined as
$$x^*(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n x_n+\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}b_n y_n,\ (a_n)\in l^1,\ (b_n)\in l^\infty$$
The [definition of dual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_norm) norm gives:
$$\|x^*\|=\sup\{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n x_n+\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}b_n y_n:\ \max{|x_n|}+\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|y_n|\leq1,\ ((x_n),(y_n))\in c_0\times l^1\}$$
Now I'm just following my intuition and not sure about rigorousness of my statements:

With $\tilde{x}=\max|x_n|\leq1$ given the value of $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n x_n$ will be maximal if $x_n=\tilde{x}\ \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. So I know following:
$$\sup\{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n x_n, \max|x_n|=\tilde{x}\}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n$$
From $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|b_n y_n|$ I get the most if I just take the highest values of $|b_n|$, because $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}|b_n y_n|$ is basicaly weighted average (so I get the most by setting the highest weight to the highest $|b_n|$). So now I have:
$$\|x^*\|=\sup\{\tilde{x}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n+(1-\tilde{x})\sup|b_n|:\ \tilde{x}\leq1\}$$
Because the expression above is again basicaly the weighted average of $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n$ and $\sup|b_n|$ I get the highest value if I just take the higher value:
$$\|x^*\|=\max\{\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}a_n,\sup|b_n|\}$$

**My questions**

1. Is the result correct?
2. Which parts are not rigorous enough for a mathematician to consider this solution to be complete?

Comment: You are missing absolute value signs around sum of summations in the definition of the dual norm.  You want a comma after "given" in the sentence where you introduce $\tilde{x}$ as well as absolute value around the summation.  Maximality presumes $a_n\ge 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: and the result is correct?

Comment: I don't know.  I may look at it further.